# Filter soql contact records using Google Location API in LWC

Tags: soql, geolocation, google

Here's what I'm trying to do:

1. Search and find a list of contact records with zip codes.
2. Filter those records using zip codes that are in 5 km radius.

I'm unable to perform the 2nd point.

Is there any document which could help me in this?

Comment: Could you not use standard Salesforce "as the crow flies" (aka great circle) distance measures, or do you need street level routing distance?

Comment: I would only have zipcode to filter the contacts. Yes, the 5km radius would be my criteria to filter. Would it be necessary to use google api or  is there an out of the box feature.

Answer (score 1):

SOQL supports [Location-Based Queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_geolocate.htm). You can retrieve records with locations within or outside of a certain radius with **DISTANCE** conditions in the WHERE clause of the query.

You can combine Distance and ZIP Code list to get the desired contacts.

Your SOQL should look this:

```
List<Contact> contactList = [Select Id, FirstName, LastName From Contact Where Distance(MailingAddress,GeoLocation(:latitude, :longitude),'km') < 5 AND MailingPostalCode IN :zipCodeList];
```

Comment: Thanks @saroj-bera. I'm confused from the salesforce documentation of Location-Based Queries. Is the MailingAddress and GeoLocation(:latitude, :longitude) on the same record? I would need all the contacts within 5 kms. Any idea on that?

Comment: @MnZ `MailingAddress` is for contact record and `GeoLocation(:latitude, :longitude)` is for the location from where you are looking for the contacts.

Comment: So do u mean "San Fransico, California" is the MailingAddress for the contact "Tom" and GeoLocation(123.123, 456.456) is the location from where the radius of 5 km will be searched? Is my understanding correct?